# download file from external link to user computer through my site in dot net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a site on Server A and my files are on Server B.
I want to download file from Server B to user computer when user click on download link on my site that is on Server B.
I know it's simple and I can use a tag but I don't want to show original download link to user because user can share this link and download without validation.
I have made this in Web Forms but I need this in Dot Net Core.
I used a handler that validated user and after validation file downloads, but in dot net core I don't know how should i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 week searching i have found the solution on [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html) blog post.
The sample code is :

```
private static HttpClient Client { get; } = new HttpClient();
[HttpGet]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> Get()
{
    var stream = await Client.GetStreamAsync("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StephenClearyExamples/AsyncDynamicZip/master/README.md");

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"))
    {
        FileDownloadName = "README.md"
    };
}
```

Comment: So to be specific, your files are on a different _web server_

Comment: Yes and it was my problem, files are on Server B. but in this way my problem solved.